# Call perl script from vbscript

Tags: perl, vbscript, arguments

I need to invoke a perl script with arguments from a  vb script. if argument contains a space in it, it is not working. Pls help.Thanks.

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sArgs = strArg1
sExec = "perl test.pl"
sCmd = sExec & " " & sArgs & " "
oShell.Run(sCmd)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can help the shell to tokenize your command by enclosing arguments in quotes.

Run directly on a shell, that might look like this:

```
C:\> perl test.pl "C:/Path with spaces/foo.temp"
```

As to how you'd do that in VBScript, we can solve that with two steps: [escape literal quotes in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458128/vbs-cmd-path-space), and [use Replace() to format that string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840767/vbscript-what-is-the-simplest-way-to-format-a-string).

```
sCmd = "perl test.pl ""{0}"""
sCmd = Replace(sCmd, "{0}", sArgs)
oShell.Run(sCmd)
```

This assumes that `sArgs` only contains one argument; if you're passing multiple arguments, you'll want to wrap each of them in quotes individually.

Comment: Using `Replace` here is pointless overhead. A simple string concatenation would suffice: `sCmd = "perl test.pl """ & sArgs & """"`

Comment: I expect the difference in performance is negligible, but in my opinion the difference in readability and ease of maintenance is not.

Comment: If you're concerned about readability use a quoting function (`Function qq(str) : qq = Chr(34) & str & Chr(34) : End Function`), so you can do the concatenation like this: `"perl test.pl " & qq(sArgs)`.